# How to disable ondemand subreport link when the value(of the link) is null or zero

Tags: crystal-reports-2008

Is there a way to disable the link (ondemand sub report link) on the report when the value is null or zero

Comment: The link should disappear and the value should not be clickable

Comment: supress the section where you added `ondemand subreport link`

Answer (score 0):

Crystal reports gives you the capability of suppressing almost anything that can be displayed on a report.

If you are suppressing the entire subreport all together, and if ALL values displayed by the subreport are null, then you can suppress the entire subreport by doing the following:

1. Right click the subreport
2. Click on "Format Subreport"
3. Then select the "Subreport" tab
4. Check the box labelled "Suppress Blank Subreport"

Does this help your issue user2220524?